# How to shift data on xAxis to right on Daniel Gindi charts?

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I have a data chart DataChart would like to shift data of xAxis along with data lines to right by certain value.

**DataChart Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Please help me out which property to use from the library that would be able to solve this purpose.

I am using Daniel Gindi line charts for this purpose.

Comment: Also I would need help on how to align the yAxis lines in front the labels. As of now there is  offset in that.

Answer (score 1):

I use this to create an offset to the left of my chart

```
myChart.xAxis.spaceMin = 10
```

maybe it'll do for you

And to align the yAxis lines in front of the labels, i think you could remove the background grid and create your own limit lines if you don't find  any other way around

Comment: Thanks @Alexandre, sapceMin did worked for me. I am still finding a way to align yAxis in front of labels. Removing the background grid would just make the chart show data without grids. Is there a way to create own limit line in Charts API? if so please share a link or sample code, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

is it viable to subtract the distance d from the x values? that would shift it rightward.

```
d = 7.0

rightShifted = newGraphData.values.map{ChartDataEntry(x:$0.x-d, y:$0.y)}
```

Comment: subtracting the distance from x values would shift the data lines in my opinion. I would want to shift the label of xAxis to right which would subsequently shift the whole plot. I gave your code a go. It is shifting the plot but not the x Axis. Thanks